# How to use react table and expand starting from the third column?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

---

When user clicks the downwards arrow, it will expand and show the grey area. It wont expand the 1st and 2nd column. How do i achieve this with React Table? [Before and after table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMfSz.png)

Comment: this will help you in expanding the columns 
[expand](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/expanding),
[sub component](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/sub-components)

Comment: But the examples shows how to expand the whole row. How do i only expand starting from the 3rd column? And not expand 1st and 2nd columns too @TahirIqbal